# global context lost between cells in jupyer lab

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

similar [to this issue,](https://github.com/TileDB-Inc/TileDB-Py/issues/644) but I have a 6.x version of ipykernel.

Is this another version mismatch problem?

cell1:
`import pathlib as pl`

cell 2:
`print(pl)`

gives:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
----> 1 print(pl)
   
NameError: name 'pl' is not defined`
```

I'm running on Fedora 35, here are versions:

```
!jupyter --version

Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.0.1
ipykernel        : 6.9.0
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.1.2
jupyter_core     : 4.9.1
jupyter_server   : 1.13.5
jupyterlab       : 3.2.9
nbclient         : 0.5.10
nbconvert        : 6.4.2
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.8
qtconsole        : 5.2.2
traitlets        : 5.1.1
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce with exact same IPython, ipykernel, ipywidgets, jupyter_client, jupyter_core, nbclient, nbformat and traitlets versions. Is this behaviour persistent or did it happen just once? Does it also happen in IPython console from within JupyterLab?

Comment: oh! that's strange. It is a hard fault for me.

I used %qtconsole in a new notebook and did the same test and it works OK.

Now I am confused